# Meaningful URL routing in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, mysql, url-routing, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to figure out a better way to generate the names of products in the URL. So instead of products being represented by their Id, I'd like the name of the products.

For example: 
https://localhost:44233/Products/Detail/Apples

***instead of***

https://localhost:44233/Products/Detail/2

So far, I've changed my routing template in my ***StartUp.cs*** file from the default to the one I've posted below. It has not worked out.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would help!

> StartUp.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Products",
    template: "{controller=Products}/{action=Detail}/{name}"
);
});
```

> Model

```
public class ProduceDetailVM
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string ProduceName {get;set;}
  public string ProducePrice {get;set;}
  public string ProduceDescription {get;set;}
}
```

> Products Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int Id, string name)
{
  var produceDetail = repoService.GetById(Id);
  var produceName   = repoService.GetByProduceName(name);

  var produceModel = new ProduceDetailVM()
{
    Id = produceDetail.Id,
    ProduceName = produceName.Name,
    ProducePrice = produceDetail.Price,
    ProduceDescription = produceDetail.Description
};

 return View(produceModel);
}
```

> RepoService

```
public class RepoService: IRepository
 {

   public ProductsTable GetById(int Id)
   {
     return _context.ProductsTable.Where(i => i.Id == Id).First();
   }

   public ProductsTable GetByProduceName(string name)
   {
     return _context.ProductsTable.Where(p => p.ProduceName == name).FirstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

> IRepository

```
 public interface IRepository
{
    ProductsTable GetById(int Id);
    ProductsTable GetByProduceName(string name);
}
```

> Detail View

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Detail Page</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <span class="image card" style="background-image:url(produceDetail.ProductImage)"></span>
        <div class="center">
            <a class="button" asp-controller="Products" action="Detail" asp-route-id="@produceDetail.ProduceName">View More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are still using the `Id` parameter in `Detail()`, which will fail if you are no longer passing in `Id` via the route. If you want to view the product detail using name alone then you should retrieve all of the product details via `name` and each product should have a unique `name`.

Comment: Thank you for that Dan. Unfortunately, the product name are not unique. Are there any other ways that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: There is no other way to approach this. If you want to access products using an identifier (`Id` or `name`) then that identifier must be unique. Either stick with `Id` or update your data such that `name` is unique.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to include both the Id as the identifier and the name? i.e. http://localhost:43222/Products/Detail/2/Apple
How would on go about doing that? Route attribute? or route mapping in startup.cs?

Answer (score 1):

> So far, I've changed my routing template in my StartUp.cs

And thus totally ignored that this is like legacy technology for years now.

Attribute routing allows you to define custom routes on every action on every controller. Especially dotnet core is being ootimized for that (with the new routing engine in 2.2 that comes out this year).

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. How would that look like?
Would this work:
[Route("Products/Detail/name")]
or 
[Route("Products/Detail/{name}")]

Comment: Second. Not sure it isa good idea though - special chars are problematic in URL's, localization may be a hugh problem. I generally avoid the approach you want to take. Oh, and read up on your IRepository - antipattern.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll look into irepo anipattern. The second route attribute did not work for me. ;(